# Old data still coming from EC2 instance in Auto Scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I have created  **ELB** (load Balancing) and Auto Scaling Group (**ASG**) after instance coming 'this is my 1st instance working fine after I have login via putty and changed the "index.html" file updated index.html ("This is my 2nd Instance updated') file then deleted instance, new instance coming old data only coming -- Here how to recover new data I mean updated instance,
I want "This is my 2nd Instance updated"

Comment: Your question is written in a really unclear way. I would recommend you to try to write a clear question that you're asking and a clear description of what you've done.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question, but it sound like your browser is caching the content. You could try clearing the cache in your browser, or try using a different browser to verify the update.

Comment: So you manually edited a file on a running instance, then killed that instance and waited for the ASG to bring up a new instance? If yes, why would you expect your manual edits to be propagated across instances?

Comment: Thank u for understanding My  Question, Then AGS to bring new instance with Updated data , How to do Steps please explain

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I followed but I think what you're saying is:
You manually SSH to the instance and update index.html, then AutoScaling launches a new instance and it doesn't have those changes.  Is that correct?

AutoScaling has no way of knowing what you did inside the instance.  AWS can't peak inside your instances and look at your data, that would be a pretty big privacy breach.

When you make updates you need to modify the launch template or launch configuration in some way to make sure the new instances have the updates.  Either:

1. Make a new AMI with the changes
2. Put the changes in a userdata script

Alternatively, you could have some sort of automation help with this such as:

1. Have a userdata script which downloads the newest files from an S3 bucket.  Just make sure to update the website files in this bucket whenever you make changes
2. Use some sort of CI/CD pipeline tool such as AWS CodeDeploy.  This will automatically push changes to your existing instances, and make sure new instances are launched with the newest code.